# Dash line in windows terminal -gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am using `gnuplot` for Windows using the default `windows` terminal. I need to plot a dashed line instead of normal solid line

I used

```
set style line 1 lt 0 lc 3
plot 'dashcca.txt'
```

but it does not work

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which `terminal` are you using exactly?

Comment: Did you try to change `lt 0` to `lt 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `help terminal windows`, which shows you the terminal option `dashed`. Either use

```
set terminal windows dashed
```

or

```
set termoption dashed
```

And of course you must use a line type which is dashed. Type `test` to see all supported line types with the current terminal settings.

In order to use a certain dash pattern with a different line color, use e.g.

```
plot x linetype 2 linecolor 1
```

This uses the dash pattern of line type 2, and the color of line type 1 (red). You can use arbitrary colors with `linecolor rgb`:

```
plot x linetype 2 linecolor rgb 'black', x**2 linetype 3 linecolor rgb '#bb0000'
```